# Lost of nuget references after deletion and cloning of the repository

Tags: c#, git, nuget

For several reasons I had to delete a solution and clone it again from my remote git repository.

After that, when you try to compile the solution, all the nuget package references were lost. I ran an Update-Package -reinstall, and this solved almost all the problems, but it generated many changes in the csproj of the solution. For example:

```
<HintPath>..\packages\Moq.4.7.145\lib\lib\net45\Moq.dll</HintPath> 
<HintPath>...\...\...\...\packages\Moq.4.7.145\lib\lib\lib\Moq.dll</HintPath>
```

This is not acceptable, as it would affect all my teammates.

I've also tried to delete and install the nuget packs, but the same thing happens.

Does anyone know what could have happened? how can I get those references working again, without modifying the csproj?

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2017 (15.5.7), but I'm doing the same thing with VS2015. Nuget is configured at the project level in a package.config, and we don't have a Nuget.config

Greetings, and thank you.

Comment: With the newly cloned solution, I ran Update-Package -reinstall, and then deleted all changes to the files it generated. I recompiled and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue few times in the past. Cleaning up some of the lines from .csproj files that refer to your packages, removing all of the package.config files, making sure Nuget.config (if any) is at proper folder level and finally fresh install of all of the packages was inevitable.